# Laravel Echo and Whisper, listenForWhisper not work

Tags: laravel, echo, whisper

I'm running Echo server and Beyondcode (Pusher). Presence channels work perfectly, and messaging I have built for it works. Now I'm trying to get the whisper to work for the typing status as well but no luck.

Sending whisper:

```
let channel = Echo.join('chat')

setTimeout( () => {
    channel.whisper('typing', {
    user: Laravel.user.id,
    typing: true
    })
}, 300)
```

Listen whisper:

```
Echo.join('chat')
.listenForWhisper('typing', (e) => {
    console.log(e)
});
```

In my echo server log, when i'm typing message:

```
testapp: connection id 332742863.966987392 received message: 
{
    "event":"client-typing",
    "data":{
        "user":2,
        "typing":true
    },
    "channel":"presence-chat"
}
```

Broadcast channel (routes/channels.php)

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return [
        'id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->name
    ];
});
```

Connection id 332742863.966987392 is second user (not the one from which I typed the message).

But nothing appears in browser console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is old, but my problem was I didn't enable an option called "Enable client events" from pusher app settings.

Answer (score 10):

Just leaving this here for future user who might be facing issue with receiving events in

```
.listenForWhisper(..)
```

If you are using **laravel-websockets**, make sure you enable
['enable_client_messages'](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/basic-usage/pusher.html#client-messages)